# How to stream movies from Google Drive to XBMC

Tags: kodi

I was wondering if there is a way I can stream movies from within my Google Drive to my Raspberry Pi running XBMC, Or could is there a plugin I would need to get to steam the movies?

Thanks in advanced,
Ondeckshooting

Comment: Google has promised us a Google Drive for Linux for a while.  I'd wait for that to come out.  ref: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2880760/google-drive-for-linux-images-leak-after-years-of-promises.html

Comment: Do you know if one of those images would work with xmbc

Comment: What do you mean images?  I'm telling you you can't do it unless you use the software shown on that site (not that I recommend it).

Comment: There are images out there but I cannot get them to work with xmbc I can only get them to work through Terminal  line

Comment: Again, what do you mean... 'images'?

Comment: Like as in binary files it's the term used with Mac and Linux to describe a package with binary executables in them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22143/discussion-between-earthmelon-and-ondeckshooting).

Answer (score -1):

You [can](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=25876&p=622923#p622923) but you may have to wait a minute before video will play